# Why does this link point to google and not yahoo?

Tags: javascript, html, events

```
<a onclick="dataBounce('http://yahoo.com');" href="http://google.com">Yahoo? :-/</a>

<script>
function dataBounce(dest) 
{
  // Note: dest is assumed to be encodeURI()ed. 
  var ie = !-[1,];

  var bouncer = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C%21doctype%20html%3E%3Cscript%3Ewindow.location%20%3D%20%27'+ dest +'%27%3B%3C/script%3E';
  console.log('bouncer: ' + bouncer);
  window.location = !ie ? bouncer : dest;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Yeah, the `href` is to google, but I have an `onclick` handler hijacking the click on the link, to navigate to a data URI which bounces the `window`'s `location` to yahoo. **However, when I click the link, I'm still taken to google. *Why?***

Why do I want to do this? It's partly just an experiment, and partly something I'd like to use in practice to protect users' privacy: by creating an intermediate bouncer page, the referrer is shielded from the destination server.

Here's the link:

http://jsbin.com/efaful/1

Comment: @VoronoiPotato it detects for IE...

Comment: Okay let me rephrase, how does this check for IE?

Comment: Speaking from the direction of SEO, I would think this would throw up a bunch of red flags, security-wise, as well, as the technique could also be used to hijack a user's browser and send it someplace they don't want to go. I'd do some research on this and make sure that you're not going to hit any Google "Quality issues" warnings.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Well, it has to do with the fact that, according to the spec, array/object literals aren't supposed to have trailing commas, but in certain browsers that like to shove screwdrivers in their peeholes, it gets parsed incorrectly and, well, the rest I don't really understand thoroughly... But I saw it on a blog somewhere once, and just tucked it away in my snippet toolbox. Hope that's useful? If it helps, IIRC crockford had an essay on his site devoted to trailing commas in JS, but that's more about philosophy, whereas this hack is just concerned with how things actually happen to

Comment: be in practice.

@mori57 SEO's not really my thing in any way/shape/form, but I'm sure some people will appreciate the warning, so take an upboat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you need to return false after doing anything in the `onclick` to prevent the default behaviour of the link.

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="dataBounce('http://yahoo.com'); return false;" />link</a>
```

Or have your `dataBounce` function return `false` and:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return dataBounce('http://yahoo.com');" />link</a>
```

Comment: @MrCode Aww, that sucks! But how is it ever getting to the stage where it performs a default action if the `window`'s `location` has changed and an entirely new DOM has been loaded? Wouldn't the present JS control flow be aborted when that happens, thus canceling the default behavior?

Comment: @MrCode want me to remove my up again? ;)

Comment: @adlwalrus the browser will essentially override your redirect if you don't prevent the default behaviour.